# blueimp file upload uploaded image rotated

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, amazon-s3, blueimp

i am uploading images to an s3 bucket using jquery and PHP. I am using blueimp's file upload plugin. the uploaded images taken on cameras arrive on the server with a width greater than the height regardless of how they were shot. images generated in Photoshop are fine in both landscape and portrait. I would prefer to solve this on the client side the JS is bellow.

**scripts**

```
<script src="https://blueimp.github.io/JavaScript-Load-Image/js/load-image.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/blueimp-file-upload/9.18.0/js/jquery.fileupload.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/blueimp-file-upload/9.18.0/js/jquery.fileupload-process.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/blueimp-file-upload/9.18.0/js/jquery.fileupload-image.min.js"></script>
```

**JQUERY**

```
form.fileupload({
    url: form.attr('action'),
    type: form.attr('method'),
    disableImageResize: false,
    imageMaxWidth: 1280,
    imageMaxHeight: 1280,
    imageOrientation: true,
    datatype: 'xml',
    add: function(event, data) {

        // Check file extention
        var ext = data.files[0].name.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();;
        if (currentItem.type == TYPE_IMAGE) {
            if ($.inArray(ext, ['gif', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg']) == -1) {
                console.log("File type not supported. Please click on the blue help icon for more information.");
                return;
            }

        } else if (currentItem.type == TYPE_MOVIE) {
            if ($.inArray(ext, ['avi', 'mpg', 'mp4', 'mov', 'wmv', 'qt', 'flv']) == -1) {
                console.log("File type not supported. Please click on the blue help icon for more information.");
                return;
            }
        }

        //check file size - 128mb limit
        var fileSize = data.files[0].size;
        if (fileSize > 134217728) {
            console.log("File over 128MB. Please click on the blue help icon for more information.");
            return;
        }

        showUploadDialog(data.files[0]);

        // Give the file which is being uploaded it's current content-type (It doesn't retain it otherwise)
        // and give it a unique name (so it won't overwrite anything already on s3).

        var filename = Date.now() + '.' + data.files[0].name.split('.').pop();
        form.find('input[name="Content-Type"]').val(data.files[0].type);
        form.find('input[name="key"]').val((folders.length ? folders.join('/') + '/' : '') + filename);

        data.submitted = new Date().getTime(); // For time remaining estimate

        // Actually submit to form to S3.
        data.submit();

    },
    progress: function(e, data) {
        updateUploadDialog(data);

    }
});
```

Comment: It would be hard to resolve this in javascript. I would suggest creating a new blanket image on backend then append image in it. then get the correct dimensions out of it. I have seen few other issues about mobile cameras not sending correct dimensions.

Comment: With `imageOrientation: true` you are explicitly instructing it to take the orientation value from the EXIF data of the image ... If that does not get set correctly by the application/device that created/took the image ... tough luck, then you will have to correct that afterwards.

Comment: @CBroe it is getting set as i can pick it up from the image on the server side

Comment: Does that work the same way if you upload the same image via FTP, and have your server-side code check the orientation then?

Comment: i have code to check it on server-side. if i upload it to s3 trough the amazon portal its fine although if i throttle the network the image loads from r to l which is top to bottom of how i upload it trough my app.